# How do I terminate Recursion once I get the desired result?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

So the following code is a leetcode problem called "Wildcard Matching".

Basically Given an input string (s) and a pattern (p), implement wildcard pattern matching with support for '?' and '*' (I am ignoring '?' at the moment).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void Match(string s, string p, int start) 
{ 
    string str;

    if(p == s)
        {
            cout<<p<<endl;
           // return true;
        }

    for(int i=start; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(p==s)
        break;

        for(int j=0; j<p.length(); j++)
        {
            if(p[j] == '*')
            {
                str = s.substr(start, i-start);
                p.replace(j,1,str);  //replace '*' with substring
                Match(s,p,start+1);  //recursion
                p.replace(j,i-start,1,'*'); //backtrack
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
    }
    cout<<p<<endl;
    //return false;
}

int main()
{
   string p = "*a*b", s = "adceb";  
   Match(s,p,0);
   return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is :-
[OUTPUT OF MY CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWPHC.png)

Basically i want the recursion to stop once I get the string value to be "adceb" (4th from top in image), but it keeps on going.

The output should look like:-

ab

adb

adcb

adceb

The queastion requires me to return boolean value that is why I need it to halt at "adceb". I output the string for debugging purposes.

Can anybody help me with this recursive solution? I did it with dynamic programming, but I want to get my recursion concepts strong and I don't know how to halt a recursion in this kind of situation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could do it by returning a certain value form the `Match()` function. For example let it return `true`. If it's true than the calling function will return true as well and so on. So you're going back up to the top.

Comment: I did try that (as you probably can see from the commented returns). The problem is it returns true once when the string matches but then returns false for every other string, so the final return value of the function is "false" Always.

Comment: Match() should not be a void function.

Comment: `Match(s,p,start+1);` needs to be `if (Match(s,p,start+1)) { return true; }` after you make `Match()` bool-returning. Most likely you recursed like this but simply discarded the result.

Comment: You should also be looping within the `*` test, not around it.

Comment: @cdhowie thank you so much, changing to `if (Match(s,p,start+1)) { return true; }` did the job. I can't thank you enough.